# HTML works in Fiddle but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to build this image slider and run it on my machine:
http://jsfiddle.net/sachin377/2patspw2/

The page is not rendering as it should. Also, I get an ActiveX warning message when using IE. Please see this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5sSg.png

What am I doing wrong?
Here is the HTML and CSS:

**Slider.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(&#39;#lightSlider&#39;).lightSlider({
                gallery: true,
                item: 1,
                loop: true,
                slideMargin: 0,
                thumbItem: 9
        });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>  
    <div>
      <div class="demo">
        <ul id="lightSlider">
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-1.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-2.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-3.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-3.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-4.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-4.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-5.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-5.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-6.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-6.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-8.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-8.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-9.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-9.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-10.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-10.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-11.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-12.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-13.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-13.jpg" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css/style.css**

```
.demo {
    width:420px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `$(&#39;#lightSlider&#39;).lightSlider({` is this in your real code?

Comment: There are lots of restrictions when just executing a html file locally.  You'd be better off creating a website in IIS and hosting it under `http://localhost`.  Particularly https will not work when you're opening a site with `file://` protocol, so your jQuery include will just not work.

Comment: Your jQuery, when the typos are fixed, needs to be run in a document.ready call or put at the end of the body. You also seem to be failing to include the lightSlider library

Comment: @LelioFaieta: I used tidy to tidy up the markup before I posted... looks like it replaced the single quote character by its ascii equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add lightslider library to your script:
CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/css/lightslider.min.css">
```

And js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
```

Also, edit this in your code:

```
$(&#39;#lightSlider&#39;).lightSlider({
```

With this:

```
$('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
```

Here is all the edited code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/css/lightslider.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>  
    <div>
      <div class="demo">
        <ul id="lightSlider">
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-1.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-2.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-3.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-3.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-4.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-4.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-5.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-5.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-6.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-6.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-8.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-8.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-9.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-9.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-10.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-10.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-11.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-12.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-13.jpg">
            <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-13.jpg" />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
                gallery: true,
                item: 1,
                loop: true,
                slideMargin: 0,
                thumbItem: 9
        });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scripts won't run if you are opening html files directly from your file system. It's a security issue.

You'll needs to have a webserver running locally on your computer to serve your files.

Check out [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mongoose/). It's simple server for windows. Here is an blog post to help you get started: https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/07/26/mongoose-simple-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding missing resources, you also need to specify the script to run when the documnet is ready. (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```css
.demo {
  width: 420px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none outside none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/js/lightslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightslider/1.1.3/css/lightslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
      gallery: true,
      item: 1,
      loop: true,
      slideMargin: 0,
      thumbItem: 9
    });
  });
</script>


<div>
  <div class="demo">
    <ul id="lightSlider">
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-1.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-2.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-3.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-3.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-4.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-4.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-5.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-5.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-6.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-6.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-7.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-7.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-8.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-8.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-9.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-9.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-10.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-10.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-11.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-12.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-13.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-13.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```